# $wpdb in the plugin, admin pages working but not the shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress

i am developing a plugin, i have queries for the admin for the back office and they are working but when i copy them and paste into a function to create a short-code the query is not working anymore.

i have a working code here like this:

```
function test(){
   include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/test.php");
}
```

and when i put the same code like this is not working anymore:

```
function test_shortcode(){
   include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/test_shortcode.php");
}
add_shortcode( 'test_shortcode', 'test_shortcode' );
```

i will appreciate any suggestion, really i can not understand why is not working. if i use mysql_connect is working in both functions, but when i use WordPress function $wpdb is working only in the first function but not in the function with the short code.

**my loop that are the same in both files:**

```
    global $wpdb;
    $TABLE_NAME       = $wpdb->prefix . "table_name";
    $RESULT = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME");
    foreach($RESULT as $RAW){
        echo $RAW->il_date
    }
```

Comment: So, the issue lies in the difference between those two files. What's different between the two, can you share them?

Comment: both files contains the loop, please look at the updated question, in the first function is working but not in the second with short code @Hammerstein

Comment: Sometimes I find that $wpdb->prefix doesn't work. I've not been able to explain it, seems random.

Comment: in my case i checked and is working correctly this $wpdb->prefix, seems the query get_result is like undefined @dwhite.me

Comment: How did you verify its the $wpdb that is not working? Just a guess here, but a shortcode should have an $atts parameter so the function is matched to it.

Comment: i did something line $wpdb->show_errors; and is displaying database error [], i did the same way a lot of short codes and they are working, first i wrote the PHPusing MySQL_ function and worked nice, after i decide to change WordPress way and when i changed nothing is working, i took the same code and run it into a function as the first one in admin pages (back office) and is working perfect when i put the same code in short code is not working, is u say i need to give a parameter can u give me a sample based on my code? @MSTannu

Comment: what database errors were you getting? $wpdb->last_error should show the relevant one.

Comment: with $wpdb->last_error; is not showing any errors @MSTannu

Comment: when i print the error in wordpress in the function of shortcode i get this, first time i see such kind of error """"""WordPress database error: []
SELECT (*) FROM pr_il_transactions """""" any ideas ....? @MSTannu